# Pass component value to header

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I'm trying to display the 'numero' of my project in my 'header' component which is displayed on all pages.

Header.component:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center px-md-4  bg-brown text-white ">

<h2 class="my-0 mr-md-auto">
<span>Project {{numero}}</span></h2>

<nav class="my-2 my-md-0 mr-md-3">
    <a class="p-2 text-white" href="#">Projects</a>
    <a class="p-2 text-white" href="#">Exit</a>
</nav>

</div>
```

Others components (.html):

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div>my component</div>
```

(.ts)

```
numero: string = "MY NUMERO";
```

How can I fill in the 'number' of my header from my other components?
Should we use @Input ()?

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a `Service`

- Declare the Service

```typescript
  export class NumeroService {
    numeroSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject("MY NUMERO")
    numero$: Observable<string> = this.numeroSubject$.asObservable();
    updateNumero(newNumero: string) {
      this.numeroSubject$.next(newNumero)
    }
  }
```

We create a `BehaviorSubject` and pass it a value "MY NUMERO". This will create an `Observable` with value "MY NUMERO". To update this value we simply pass the new value to the `next()` function of the `Subject`

- We then inject this service in the `HeaderComponent`
  **TS**

```typescript
  constructor (private numeroService: NumeroService) {}
  numero$ = this.numeroService.numero$
```

**HTML**

```html
  <span>Project {{ numero$ | async }}</span></h2>
```

We are using `async` pipe to subscribe to the `Observable`

- Finally we inject the service where we wish to update the `numero$`

```typescript
  constructor (private numeroService: NumeroService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.numeroService.updateNumero("NEW NUMERO")
  }
```

Comment: Great, glad to have helped